# FindElementXpath how to get the raw data value

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

does anyone know how to get the data-raw value of "44697000000000" using FindElementXpath and write the result to excel intead of the 44,697,000 M

example of element

td class="rowval val1 " data-percentage="100" data-raw="44697000000000" data-value-idr="44697000000000" data-value-usd="3852820608.132629">44,697,000 M</td

using
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='data_table_40']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").Text

I just get the "44,697,000 M"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='data_table_40']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").Attribute("data-raw")
```

Comment: @QHarr - thanks I didn't know the selenium basic method was different...